# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting on line 319

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I keep getting the error below..

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION),
>   expecting on line 319

for the theme-woocommerce.php file.

I have tried using numerous code checkers and none have found a problem on line 319 of the code. This is frustrating as I have not edited the code, rather have copied and pasted a section out and then repasted it into the editor. Having done that, my whole website now does not work. Can someone please help? I read something about Mac computers changing the format of text when copied and pasted... Can someone shed some light here?

Below is line 319 from the theme-woocommerce.php file.

```
$params = apply_filters( 'mystile_homepage_product_categories_params', 'number=""' );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_STRING, expecting T\_FUNCTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335096/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-expecting-t-function)

Comment: Would check the encoding type of the text editor.

Comment: all good guys I found that I had to go back to my host and change the code there rather than through wordpress's editor. The theme-woocommerce.php file on the host was missing line 318, and a few other lines! The site is working fine now. Cheers!

Comment: please check, you have give same name of function for filter :"mystile_homepage_product_categories_params"

Answer (score 3):

Code is fine. You may need to look around line 319, not just literally at that only one, as you may have unmatched brackets or quotes earlier or any other syntax error. Just look for closest method declaration and see if previous code block is closed correctly.